# How to understand the colon operator usage in a Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning both Ruby (2.3.x) & Rails (4.x). I was going through the [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning) and I encountered this syntax and am having trouble reading it:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,  presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Does this class define `validates` as a method which takes in a `:name` symbol and a hash `presence:true`? The same thing applies to line 3.

Or it is something entirely else? All attempts to run it resulted in:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord.
```

I looked at the [source(maybe?)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5bb1d4d288d019e276335465d0389fd2f5246bfd/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104) but am still not clear.

Comment: It doesn't define `validates`, it's using the predefined `validates` method.

Comment: When you mentioned attempting to run the code did you run it as part of a Rails application or did you try it as part of a standalone Ruby script?

Comment: @mikej Just copy pasted in IRB so standalone I'd assume.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Then that's why you got the error. You don't have the prerequisite `require` statements. Run it in the context of Rails.

Comment: `validates( :name, { :presence => true } )` would be the complete syntax. It's more verbose, but it makes it easier to identify the method, the number and the types of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) is implemented as a class method in [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

The `ActiveModel::Validations` module is included in `ApplicationRecord`, therefore you are able to call that method when your `User` class is loaded.

`validates` accepted an array and treats the last element of that array as an options hash (if the last element is an hash).

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing. The OP asked "Does this class define validates as a method" and you've said that's correct - however the code is calling a method, not defining one.

Comment: Hmm, I read that as "does this class (`ApplicationRecord`) define `validates` as a method"...

Answer (score 2):

This is a special DSL introduced by ApplicationRecord. What you are actually doing is calling those methods inside class during declaration. It adds those validations to your class, so whenever you try to save a record it will fail if you don't have email or name

Try this

```
user = User.new
user.save
user.valid? # false
```

And try to do the same without `validates`.

If it will make things more clear for you, you can try write this class like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates(:name, presence: true)
  validates(:email, presence: true)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`validates` is a pre-defined `helper` that Active Record offers to use in Rails to make the validation work easier, this way you can with some single lines of code manage several validations of several attributes.

As it's a `helper` within Rails it's also a `method` defined in the `ActiveModel` module, in the core of the framework, see: [active_model/validations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4642d68d8021893c69bfd16ed6e926ae03a6d777/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L151)

The most common is the `presence` `attribute` which you're facing the trouble with, that specifies that the attribute used isn't empty, doing it in the Ruby way through the `blank?` method to check if the value passed isn't `blank` nor `nil`.